# django joining 2 tables which has 2 foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 tables say TableA and TableB

```
   class A(models.Model)
      A_name = models.CharField(max_length=48,primary_key=True)
      A_version = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0,null=False,blank=False)
      A_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
      class Meta:
             unique_together = ("A_name", "A_version") 

   class B(models.Model)
     B_number = models.CharField(max_length=32 ,primary_key=True)
     A_name = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name="AA_name",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
     A_version = models.ForeignKey(A,related_name="AA_version",on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
         class Meta:
             unique_together = ("B_number","A_name", "A_version")
```

Now i want to do something like this: 
        select * from A, B where B.B_name=A.A_name and B.B_version=A.A_version and     A.A_type="type_name". I can't perform a get as A_type is not unique and it can return mutiple objects. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this answers your question but if you want to get all objects with only one query by using join, you can use `select_related`:

```
all_b = B.objects.all().select_related('A_name', 'A_version')
some_b = all_b[0]
some_b.A_name # does not incur extra db query
```

If you want more control of the query, you can always add filters:

```
B.objects.filter(A_name__A_type='type_name').select_related('A_name', 'A_version')
```

Comment: miki725, I want all data from TableB which have  A_type="type_name"

Comment: from which foreign key, A_name or A_version?

Comment: adjusted answer which for A_name

Comment: Both, Basically i want all the data from TableB which has A_type=typename and the TableA and TableB should be joined based on A_name and A_version

Comment: Hey sorry miki725 i just saw the other piece of code you posted. I did that change but now am getting a database error. The error says:

Comment: Caught DatabaseError while rendering: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server', u"Invalid column name 'A_name_id'.", None, 0, -2147217900), None)

Comment: Command:
SELECT  [db_name].[A_name_id], [db_name].[A_version_id],  [A].[A_name], [A].[A_version], [A].[A_type], T3.[A_name], T3.[A_version],  T3.[A_type] FROM [db_name] INNER JOIN [A] ON ([db_name].[A_name_id] = [A].[A_name]) INNER JOIN [A] T3 ON ([db_name].[A_version_id] = T3.[A_name]) WHERE [A].[A_type] = ? 
Parameters:
[Name: p0, Dir.: Input, Type: adBSTR, Size: 9, Value: "type_name", Precision: 0, NumericScale: 0]

Comment: are you sure you have field `A_name` within your model `B`? That is what the error seems to be about.

Comment: yup i have A_name as a foreign key within model B

Comment: Don't know. I do queries like that all the time and it works fine. Although I use postgres for db. Which Django version are you using?

Comment: This is the raw sql query that am getting. Am using django 1.3.3 SELECT  [B].[A_name_id], [B].[A_version_id],  [A].[A_name], [A].[A_version], [A].[A_type], T3.[A_name], T3.[A_version], T3.[A_type] FROM [B] INNER JOIN [A] ON ([B].[A_name_id] = [A].[A_name]) INNER JOIN [A] T3 ON ([B].[A_version_id] = T3.[A_name]) WHERE [A].[A_type] = Physician

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the design of the models is very good. The A model has A_name and A_version as unique together. That means that there will always be ONE object which has a unique composition of A_name and A_version.

In model B you can reference the ID field because that will give you the unique combination A_name and A_version.

What you need to do in B:s save method is to make sure that no new or existing records gets the same B_number and A reference as already exsiting in the DB

```
 class B(models.Model)
     B_number = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True) #Don't use as primary key
     A        = models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def save(self, *args, **kvargs):
        if self.id:
            try:
                b_s = B.objects.get(B_number=self.B_number, A=self.A).exclude(pk=self.id)

                #The existing combination already exists:
                raise ValueError('The combination of B_number and A already exists')

            except B.DoesNotExist:
                #No existing records violates the rule
                pass
        else:
            try:
                b_s = B.objects.get(B_number=self.B_number, A=self.A)

                #The existing combination already exists:
                raise ValueError('The combination of B_number and A already exists')

            except B.DoesNotExist:
                #No existing records violates the rule
                pass

         #All is good, no violation
         super(B, self).save(*args, **kvargs)
```

Once this is in place you know for sure that when you run a query on A_type the underlying B:s are unique

Example data:

```
ID        A_name        A_version    A_type
 1        "name1"       1.0          "type1"
 2        "name2"       1.1          "type1"
 3        "name2"       1.2          "type2"

 Model B
 ID  B_number  A
 1    "10"     1
 2    "20"     1
 3    "30"     2
 4    "40"     3

#Will return A.id=1 and A.id=2
a_s = A.objects.filter(A_type="type1")

for a in a_s:
    for b in a.b.all():
        print b.number, a.A_number, a.A_version
```

I make a reservation for typos since I haven't got the time to test it myself.